# How to Separate Commas and save the values in a Matrix Array.

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, matrix

I have the following dataset and i want to separate the txt values and commas and save to a 10x18 matrix. 
I tried with str2mat(char(txt(...)) but it didn't help. It separates the value and make individual character. How can I save the data in matrix.

```
'1,4,5,12,13,17,22,24,25,21,20,17,12,12,10,9,8,4'
'2,4,6,7,9,10,13,15,17,17,14,13,12,11,9,7,5,2'
'3,7,8,10,11,13,14,15,18,18,16,15,14,11,10,5,4,2'
'5,5,8,9,15,17,18,20,21,22,21,17,15,14,12,11,6,2'
'5,6,8,10,14,15,19,21,24,19,17,16,14,13,10,5,3,2'
'4,6,7,9,10,13,17,19,20,20,19,17,16,12,11,9,7,1'
'6,7,12,16,19,20,21,22,24,24,22,17,9,6,4,3,2,1'
'4,8,10,11,14,16,18,22,24,22,21,19,18,13,8,6,5,4'
'1,3,11,12,14,15,17,18,22,21,20,16,15,14,11,7,6,2'
'2,5,11,15,18,19,22,26,27,25,22,17,9,8,7,4,2,1'
```

Comment: If what you have is a cell array of char vectors, in your code you can just replace `str2mat` by `str2num` (but beware: `str2num` uses `eval` under the hood, and so it is dangerous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as:

```
text = '1,2,3':
nums = strsplit(text,',');
vals = str2double(nums);
```